# AppVeyor install throwing "Failed to add user to group" error

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, windows-server-2016, appveyor, windows-server-2019

I’m trying to install Appveyor Server on an instance of Windows Server to create a CI/CD pipeline, and each time I try to run the installer, it fails. I’m using the appveyor-server-7.0.2353-win-x64.msi install file.

First I spun up a Windows Server 2019 instance and attempted the install. I got an error that says

`Failed to add user to group. (-2147023509 appveyor  Administrators  )`

After that, I deleted that server and spun up an instance of Windows Server 2016 and tried it. I got the exact same error, on a totally different machine. Both machines were just created. I tried to find something online about this error, but couldn’t find any information. I found one instance where someone got this error, but there were no answers about it. Any idea what’s causing this or what I could do to get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

The name of the machines I created were both "AppVeyor". When AppVeyor installs, it attempts to create a new user called "appveyor" and adds it to the Administrators group. If the machine name is "appveyor" (regardless of case), that user cannot be created. This error would also occur if the admin user (possibly any user, but I can't confirm that) was named "appveyor".

I changed the name of my machine and AppVeyor installed just fine.

Update: [AppVeyor is now fixing it](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/3074)